# How to manage custom adapters onPause , onResume of Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, android-adapter

I have an adapter used to display messages on the list view alike messages in chat application . I am able to display the content flawlessly once the activity is created , but when I go back and create activity again , adapter don't work as usual .

What I found in debugging is follows:

- function receives() is called when message is received and update the
  register , as I mentioned above there is no problem to display the
  data in list view once the activity is created , but once I go back
  and relauch the activity I am not able to display received messages .

Is there something I am missing in onResume() onPause or onStart() method with respect to custom adapter such as registering or decalring the custom adapter again? Thanks for help.

Following is the code of my activity class which uses custom adapter to display sent and received messages:

```
public class hotListener extends ListActivity {


    private XMPPConnection connection;
    private IBinder binder;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<ChatMessage> messagex= new ArrayList<ChatMessage>();;
    ChattingAdapter adaptex;

    Intent mIntent ;
    private ListView listview;
    EditText sender_message ;
    String msg;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listener);
        //messagex.add(new ChatMessage("Hello", false));
        adaptex  = new ChattingAdapter(getApplicationContext(),messagex);
        setListAdapter(adaptex);

        Button send_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chat_send_message);
        sender_message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.chat_input);
        send_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                msg = sender_message.getText().toString();
                sender_message.setText("");
                if(!(msg.length()==0)){
                    messagex.add(new ChatMessage(msg, true));
                    //addNewMessage(new ChatMessage(msg, true));
                    adaptex.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    getListView().setSelection(messagex.size()-1);
                }

            }
        });
        if(!isMyServiceRunning()){
            System.out.println("seems like service not running");
            startService(new Intent(this,xService.class));
            System.out.print(" now started ");
        }       
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Boolean kuch = bindService(new Intent(this,xService.class), mConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        //System.out.println(kuch);
        System.out.println("bind done");        
    }

    private void receives(XMPPConnection connection2) {
            //ChatManager chatmanager = connection.getChatManager();
            connection2.getChatManager().addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {

                @Override
                public void chatCreated(Chat arg0, boolean arg1) {
                    arg0.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {

                            final String from = message.getFrom();
                            final String body = message.getBody();
                            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                ChatMessage kudi = new ChatMessage(body, false);

                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    messagex.add(kudi);
                                    adaptex.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    getListView().setSelection(messagex.size()-1);
                                    Toast.makeText(hotListener.this,body,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for(RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)){
            if(xService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())){
                return true;
            }
        }
        //System.out.print("false");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        bindService(new Intent(this, xService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        super.onResume();
      }
     @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        super.onPause();
      }

     private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                connection = null;
                service = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
                //System.out.println("binding in hot listener");
                service = ((xService.MyBinder)binder).getService();
                connection = service.getConnection();
                receives(connection);
                Log.wtf("Service","connected");
            }
        };

        void addNewMessage(ChatMessage m)
        {
            System.out.println("1");
            messagex.add(m);
            System.out.println("2");
            adaptex.notifyDataSetChanged();
            System.out.println("3");
            getListView().setSelection(messagex.size()-1);
        }
}
```

Here is my custom adapter (there is no problem in custom adapter but adding to make things clear) :

```
public class ChattingAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ChatMessage> mMessages;


    public ChattingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ChatMessage> messages) {
        super();
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mMessages = messages;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mMessages.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return mMessages.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChatMessage message = (ChatMessage) this.getItem(position);

        ViewHolder holder; 
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
            holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());
        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.message.getLayoutParams();      

        //Check whether message is mine to show green background and align to right

        if(message.isMine())

        {           holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.msgbox_new_selected_go_up);         

                lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;     
        }
        //If not mine then it is from sender to show orange background and align to left

        else        
        {
            holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.msgbox_other_go_up);

            lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        }
            holder.message.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //holder.message.setTextColor(R.color.textColor);   

        return convertView;
    }
    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView message;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        //Unimplemented, because we aren't using Sqlite.
        return position;
    }

}
```

p.s: I am not storing any messages in sqlite as I dont want to restore messages for now, but I want new messages to be displayed at least onresume of activty. I can display sent messages after pressing send button but no received messages which works fine for the first time activity is created.

EDIT: I did more debugging , it turns out problem is not in resume activity , if I dont use receives() function for first time , and resume activity after going back , then receives() will work , that means , function inside receives()  :                                     `getListView().setSelection(messagex.size()-1);` works only once . 
Either first time on receiving message or next time if and only if its not called first time on activity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem lies when you try to resume activity , you are still running the previous mHandler running and thus your instance of message is not destroyed and when you resume your activity it creates a problem . Make sure your mhandler destroys all instance of objects when unstop is called.

Comment: but I did try to stop looper using looper.quit in onDestroy method , application crashes . I did try mhandler.removeCallbackAndMessages(null); without looper.quit which fails as well

Comment: It did helped me in some other form , all I did was using static to create single instance of messagex and it did the trick but there is one last resort , received message is displayed only when i send message

Answer (score 1):

There's no place in your code where you save your `messagex` ArrayList. When you quit your activity by hitting back, your array get's distroyed (Garbage Collection takes care of it).

When you relaunch your activity your `messagex` ArrayList is created again, it's a brand new variable.

In fact, you're not **relaunching** your activity, you're creating a new instance.

EDIT:

I've never worked with the XMPPConnection objects before, but something else worth trying is the following:
When binding to the service, you're calling `connection2.getChatManager().addChatListener` and also `arg0.addMessageListener` but when unbinding you're not calling any `removeXXX` methods. I could be that since you're not removing your listeners, the whole XMPPConnection object still have references to the listeners that live in a dead Activity, and they are not being garbage collected.

Comment: yes , I dont want to restore the previous messages , but new messages are not displayed either on blank list view once I resume on activity . I can see sent messages after pressing send button on resume of activity but no received messages. I can see in debugger that receives function is called and Toast is also done but it is not changing adapter data. Thanks for your time

Comment: Hmm, The only suspicious thing I see is the toast message inside the Runnable object. Never update UI, including toasts, from a thread other than the main thread.

Comment: Ok , will remove and see if it changes anything but its highly unlikely , because once activity is created for first time , both display and Toast works fine , and once I go back and come to activity again only Toast works . There is something I am missing with respect to adapter and since i am noob in android I am clueless , tried dubgging to understand what could be wrong , but control does go inside receives() function

Comment: I did more debugging , it turns out problem is not in resume activity , if I dont use receives() function for first time , and resume activity after going back , then receives() will work , that means , receives()  :                                     getListView().setSelection(messagex.size()-1); works only once!

Comment: is it because my looper.loop is still running for the last mhandler ? I did debugger on custom adapter inside my receives function and it turns out for first time when I call receives my looper.loop runs for a while and then moves to main thread to display message , but second time its more like a never ending loop , I am on this problem for more than 6 hours now , lot of mysteries coming out , thanks for your time , reading a lot of details